# URL tuckey - query string

Tags: java, spring, url-rewriting, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I have a url for ex: http://dominename:port/first/1/second/2/third/3 and want to rewrite to 
http://dominename:port/first=1/second=2/third=3. I can get to first and get 1. But for two and three how can I get it?

below is my code to get first:

```
 <rule>
    <from>^/first/(.*)$</from>
    <to type="forward">/dominename:port/first=1</to>
</rule>
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you would like an answered then you need to add more info. For example what language is this or is this a setting for an framwork/service?

Comment: we are using spring framework and java and tucky URL rewrite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You access the regular replacement expressions by `$1` , `$2`, ...

```
<rule>
    <from>^/first/(.*)/second/(.*)/third/(.*)$</from>
    <to type="forward">/first=$1/second=$2/third=$3</to>
</rule>
```

**But that will not work, because you can not have `=` in the path of an url!**

So what you may should do is this:

```
<rule>
    <from>^/first/(.*)/second/(.*)/third/(.*)$</from>
    <to type="forward">something?first=$1&second=$2&third=$3</to>
</rule>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. is there a way to do the rules seperately? like do the first as rule 1 and store it in a variable and search for second and apply the rule. thanks!

Comment: I am not sure what you want to do, but tucky URL is not a programming language, so I think the answer is: no. Anyway have a look at its doku.

Comment: Thanks, Ralph! Your answer helped me fix my problem. Thanks for insight.

Comment: Hey @Ralph I am doing the same thing, this is my rule     

      <rule>
         <from>^/project/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)</from>
         <to>/project.jsp?user_id=$1&project_id=$2</to>
     </rule>
   
this is giving me an error "The reference to entity "project_id" must end with the ';' delimiter." ....when I remove "&" symbol then it dont show any error..

Comment: Maybe you need to escape the ampersand.

Comment: @vikasdevde: Use &amp; instead of & in XML files.